# Start Broadcast Receiver from an activity in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I would like to start a broadcast receiver from an activity. I have a Second.java file which extends a broadcast receiver and a Main.java file from which I have to initiate the broadcast receiver. 
I also tried doing everything in Main.java as follows but didn't know how to define in manifest file...

### Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
String rec_data = "Nothing Received";
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if( intent.getStringExtra("send_data")!=null)
                    rec_data = intent.getStringExtra("send_data");
            Log.d("Received Msg : ",rec_data);
        }
    }; 
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        //intentFilter.addDataType(String);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }

  @Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.myReceiver);
}

}
```

If I cannot do everything in one class as above, how can I call the Broadcast Receiver from Main.java? Can anyone please let me know where I'm doing it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: if  i understand correctly you jst wnt 2 seperate BroadcastReciever...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use this why to send a custom broadcast:

Define an action name:

```
public static final String BROADCAST = "PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast";
```

AndroidManifest.xml register receiver :

```
<receiver android:name=".myReceiver" >  
    <intent-filter >  
        <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast"/>  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Register Reciver :

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST);
registerReceiver( myReceiver , intentFilter);
```

send broadcast from your Activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST);  
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();  
        extras.putString("send_data", "test");  
        intent.putExtras(extras);  
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

YOUR BroadcastReceiver :

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
           if (extras != null){  
           {
                    rec_data = extras.getString("send_data");
            Log.d("Received Msg : ",rec_data);
            }
        }
    };
```

for more information for Custom Broadcast see [Custom Intents and Broadcasting with Receivers](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

Comment: Thanks so much replying! I tried doing it but myReceiver is not receiving any message... Instead, I get this message in the Logcat: Emulator without GPU emulation detected. I tried to enable the GPU emulation of the emulator but then it said Snapshot and GPU factors cannot be true simultaneously. I unchecked the snapshot factor. But still am not getting the message...

Comment: I forgot to mention that my sender and receiver are from two different apps

Answer (score 2):

check this tutorial here you will get all help about broadcast including how to start service from activity or vice versa

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to broadcast a intent for the receiver, see the code below :-

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You can set the action and other properties of Intent and can broadcast using the Application context, Whatever action of Intent you set here that you have to define in the AndroidManifest.xml with the receiver tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5473750/928361

I think if you don't specify anything in the `IntentFilter`, you need to tell the intent the receiver class.