# Broadcast receiver is not getting invoked

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I have used a Broadcast Receiver which is to be invoked when it finds internet Connection on the android device, to check if the Broadcast Receiver is running or not I have tried printing it in the logcat. I have no message being displayed.
I am invoking a service in my broadcast receiver which is also not getting invoked. 
I have seen similar questions on stack overflow but still I am unable to solve the issue.
I am stuck with this since many days. Can anybody help me solve this problem?

This is my Broadcast receiver:

```
public final class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e("BRRRRRRRRRR","works!!!! In Broadcast Receiver...!!!");


        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        final PendingIntent wakeupIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, LocationUpdate.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

       final boolean hasNetwork = !intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if (hasNetwork)
        {

            // start service now for doing once
            context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationUpdate.class));

            // schedule service for every 15 minutes
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, wakeupIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            alarmManager.cancel(wakeupIntent);
        }

    }
 }
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <receiver    android:name="info.androidhive.loginandregistration.ConnectivityReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: are you sure that you even started your receiver ?

Comment: is this info.androidhive.loginandregistration.ConnectivityReceiver your Receiver and your packkage is info.androidhive.loginandregistration?

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri  Shouldn't the broadcast receiver be invoked automatically depending on the action specified in the intent filter??

Comment: @El_Mochiq Yes dats right.

Comment: @SyedYusuf you have to register it, look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972769/start-broadcast-receiver-from-an-activity-in-android

Comment: @El_Mochiq  I have registered the Broadcast Receiver it in the manifest file. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @SyedYusuf you also have to do it from your activity, the thread that I mentioned in the precious comment has all steps to get that done. Check if you have done all steps please.

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver looks fine. Please, check if your package name is correct. Registering receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml` should me sufficient, but if it doesn't work for some reason, you can try different solution.

Try to register your receiver programmatically in the following way e.g. in `onResume()` method in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   ConnectivityReceiver receiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
   filter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
   registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

You should also unregister your receiver in `onPause()` method in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

If it won't help, you can add new permissions to AndroidManifest.xml file inside the  tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Sir I am not sure where should I place the above piece of code which registers the broadcast receiver. Can you please explain further?

Comment: I've edited my question. I think it's more clear now. I don't know structure of your application, but if you want to receive an information about changing connection in Activity, you should register Broadcast receiver in `onResume()` method and unregister it in `onPause()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking connectivity changes, i suggest you can first check if your app has permissions to connect to the internet.

The permission for the app to access the internet would be -
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`