# How can I start receiver class from an Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, receiver

I have an activtiy and a receiver.class with broadcastreceiver. I would like to start receiver from mainactivity but I could not do this with my solution.

Here is may way

```
Intent iinent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyReceiver.class);
        startActivity(iinent);
```

When I try this app says me Unfortunately app has stopped'' and my logcat says this intent' line s incorrect.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can not start broadcast receiver like activity. You can register and un-register broadcast receiver.

Comment: have you registered your broadcastreceiver? You can send broadcasts via intent

Comment: More details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972769/start-broadcast-receiver-from-an-activity-in-android

Comment: Oh thanks. I will try regsiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Sending Broadcast Receiver Broadcast Receiver must be registered

in Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="TestReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_NAME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In Activity

```
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
      filter.addAction("ACTION_NAME");

   BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //do something based on the intent's action
    }
  }
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);



SendBroadcast


 Intent intnet = new Intent("ACTION_NAME");
    sendBroadcast(intnet);
```

Comment: Thanks but I cant run this. 4. "}"  underlined in red. Something wrong on me?

Comment: you will have to make whole program.
please check http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html