# How to start the broadcastreceiver the app is starting in android?

Tags: android

```
  <receiver
    android:name="com.orcatracker.functions.BootService">
    <intent-filter >
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

How to start the receiver when the app is starting ? I have used  below permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: You don't start that Receiver. It will run when it receives the `BOOT_COMPETED` broadcast from the system. Make sure you have the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

Comment: Check [this link](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-BroadCast-Tutorial)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972769/start-broadcast-receiver-from-an-activity-in-android

Comment: already i did it Mike M

Answer (score -1):

Following Code is used to call BROADDCAST RECEIVER:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,BootCompletedIntentReceiver.class);
 sendBroadcast(intent);// this line is use to start broadcast.
```